# Dynamic access control in openldap ldap

Tags: openldap

dI am trying to use openldap as a central authentication system as well as storing some data based on the user type.

My ldap DIT structure is as follows

```
                      domain
Superuser             Users                data
              User1   user2   user3     Entry1  Entry2
```

With every user entry I have fixed auth string,.. example-
for user1

```
authstring=Entry1-RW   #allowing entry1 to be readable and writable
authstring=Entry2.R    #allowing entry2 to be readable
```

and similarly for user2

```
authstring=*.RW       #allowing all entries to be readable and writable
```

How can I define my slapd.conf without hardcoding all the cases to achieve this functionality?
Usually we can only define the the access control with dn.
**can I restrict the access control definitions using attrs?**

like

```
access to dn.regex=uid=[^,]ou=data,dc=my-domain,dc=com
    by dn="uid=.*,ou=users,dc=my-domain,dc=com" filter=authstring=$1.RW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do the following:(uid is the attribute of data entry it could be cn also)

```
access to dn.regex="uid=[^,]+,ou=data,dc=my-domain,dc=com" 
    by set.expand="this/uid & user/authstring" write
```

But still the problem is that I have to write separate attr for each dataEntry and each type of permission
Example:
For user1:

```
authstringread:Entry1
authstringreadwrite:Entry2
```

and the access control settings would be

```
access to dn.regex=uid=[^,],ou=data,dc=my-domain,dc=com
    by set.expand="this/uid & user/authstringreadwrite" write
    by set.expand="this/uid & user/authstringread"      read
```

Answer (score -3):

You can certainly restrict the ACL methods using attrs either way :

## For user1 :

```
aci: (targetattr=*)(targetfilter="(entryCategory=Entry1)")(version 3.0; acl "read-write"; allow (read, write)userdn ="ldap:///uid=user1,dc=example,dc=com";)
aci: (targetattr=*)(targetfilter="(entryCategory=Entry2)")(version 3.0; acl "read"; allow (read)userdn ="ldap:///uid=user1,dc=example,dc=com";)
```

## For user2 :

```
aci: (targetattr=*)(targetfilter="(|(entryCategory=Entry1)(entryCategory=Entry2)")(version 3.0; acl "read-write"; allow (write)userdn ="ldap:///uid=user2, dc=example,dc=com";)
```

Similarly, you can allow anyone to have specific read or write access.

```
aci: (version 3.0; acl "anonymous-read-search";allow (read, write) userdn = "ldap:///anyone";)
```

or

## For specific user set :

```
userdn = "ldap:///uid=b*,c=example.com ||ldap:///cn=b*,dc=example,dc=com";
```

Checkout this link for more readings :

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22289_01/html/821-1277/bind-rule-syntax.html#defining-anonymous-access-anyone-keyword

Hope this helps.

Thanks, John

Comment: Wrong product. He is asking about OpenLDAP.

Comment: These ACI are not product specifics. The link is only as a helper.

Comment: I am not sure if we can write it this way in openldap I will try...Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as an ACI in OpenLDAP. Ergo you are still talking about the wrong product. -1

Comment: We only have term  ACL=access control list but (AFAIK) we can't write rules in similar manner